# d3 transition not working on exit/remove

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a multi-line graph that updates when a user clicks a button. On some of the updates, the data is completely different, so it just exits those lines and adds new lines, which is all working. I am trying to add a transition to exit/remove so that the removal is cleaner. No matter what I do, I can't get the transition on the exit/remove to work. I have tried delaying the transition and setting it to start when the update transition is done.

Here is the code with transitions that is in the update function:

```
//bind data 
series = svg.selectAll(".series")
        .data(seriesData, function (d) { return d.name; });

 //draw new lines
    newlines = series.enter().append("g").attr("class","series");
    newlines.append("path")
      .attr("d", function (d) {return line(d.values); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
            div.transition("tooltipIn")
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9)})
          .on("mouseout", function(d){
            div.transition("tooltipOut")
                .duration(500)
                .style("opacity", 0);
    });

    //change the line
    series.select("path")
        .transition("pathTrans")
        .duration(6000)
        .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.values); })

     series.exit()
        .transition('exitTrans')
        .duration(7000)
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .each('start.exit', function (d) {console.log(d.name + ' start') })
        .each('end.exit', function (d) { console.log(d.name + ' end') })
        .remove();

    svg.select(".y.axis")
        .transition("yaxisTrans")
        .duration(2000)
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.select(".x.axis")
        .transition("xaxisTrans")
        .duration(2000)
        .call(xAxis);

    //change grid lines
    svg.select(".grid")
        .transition("gridTrans")
        .duration(2000)
        .call(makeYGrid()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

 series.select("transition")
        .each("interrupt", function(d){console.log("interrupted");});
```

Can someone explain how to get the exit transition to actually work?

Comment: You seem to have a typo there -- `transition.transition()` after the `.exit()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I've tried it with just transition too. Adding the extra was one of the things I tried. According to the [d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#transition) transition.transition():

"Creates a new transition on the same selected elements that starts when this transition ends. The new transition inherits this transition’s duration and easing. This can be used to define chained transitions without needing to listen for "end" events." Will edit it out of the above post for clarity though.

Comment: It's been a while since I used animation in d3 but it seems like you are not actually transitioning to anything - for example to fade the elements out, would you not do something like `stuff.transition().attr('opacity', 0).remove()` ?

Comment: The code as you have posted it are two separate statements: `series.exit()` and `transition().duration(6000).remove();` This won't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Maybe the one @LarsKotthoff mentioned is a typo? Either way, it would be much clearer if you include the code where you do the data join.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I added a period that was missing in front of transition. Is that what you mean? There was a period in my version -- I had inadvertently taken it out in the post. I edited it to add it back in. If that and the double transition aren't what you mean, sorry I am still unclear...

Comment: @CoolBlue The file is like 700 lines. The exit/remove is working but the transition isn't. Shouldn't that mean that it isn't the selection? If not, certainly let me know and I will try to add something more that is more in-depth.

Comment: @rom99 Just tried that and still isn't transitioning. :-/

Comment: @snowdragon Well in general this is the way to do it -- http://jsfiddle.net/gqwf3z4y/ Maybe you have something else interfering with the transition?

Comment: Just show the statement where you join the data.... As always @LarsKotthoff has a good point, put an `.each("interrupt", function (d) {…})` on the transition to see if it's interrupted and anyway you should name the transitions to eliminate collisions. Which transition isn't running anyway?

Comment: @CoolBlue Added the data join statement. The exit transition is the one that isn't running, although they are being exited and removed -- it just isn't transitioning. Can you give an example of how to do it with named transitions?

Comment: Did you check if it was interrupted? …`series.exit().transition('exitTrans').duration(`…

Comment: @CoolBlue I added the below code and neither is producing a log statement. Not sure if this is how to do the interrupt.                                          series.exit()
            .transition('exitTrans')
            .each("interrupt", function(d){ console.log("interrupted");})
            .duration(6000)
            .attr("opacity", 0)
            .remove(); AND 
        series.select("transition")
            .each("interrupt", function(d){ console.log("interrupted");});

Comment: I assume you have `series.exit() .transition('exitTrans').duration(6000).style("opacity", 0).remove()`.  you can also put a log on the start of the transitions `.transition('exitTrans').duration(6000).style("opacity", 0).each('start.exit', function () { console.log(d.name + ' start') }).each('end.exit', function () { console.log(d.name + ' end') }).remove()` There are a lot of ways to poke around and see what's going on... just use your imagination.   Also, update your post to reflect the current state of the code...

Comment: @CoolBlue Updated. So it still isn't transiting. It's printing the names of the lines that are supposed to be exiting but it is printing the start and end after the lines have already been removed, when I increase the duration of the transition, it makes the end statement come later but doesn't impact when the lines are actually removed. Any ideas?